# I can see data in console but CANNOT grab it. parent to child callback in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I've have an input box that is pulling data from the youtube API and outputting. results so far I'm seeing Json when I type results but I cannot grab any data.

Parent Component

```
import Searching from "./Searching";

class App extends Component {
  // constructor(props){
  //   super(props);

  //   this.state = {
  //     applications: ""
  //   }
  // }

  yourCallback(searchResults) {
    console.log("searchResults", searchResults); 
  }

  render() {
  // console.log ('this.props', this.props)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Searching
           callback={this.yourCallback}
        />
      <br/>
      <h1>{this.searchResults}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

so, in the console I see:

[image]

Ideally I will need to create a SearchItem component and then pass a property that contains data from this API, such as videoId or something else. However, I need to see that I can grab data from it and output inside a div or and h1 tag. What am I doing wrong?, I cannot grab this data even tough I can see it in the console.

Comment: I would like to bring to your attention that the code structure is bad.The purpose of components in React is to render a component.Your 3rd party calls should be taken out from the component and instead be put inside another files - in React we call them actions. You can then import the actions and trigger the API call accordingly. 

You should also use a state management. Redux would be perfect for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just manage a `state` in Parent component and set that state in your callback like this:

```
class App extends Component {
     constructor(props){
      super(props);
       // Maintain a state
       this.state = {
         searchResults: ""
       }
       // Bind yourCallback like this
       this.yourCallback = this.yourCallback.bind(this);
     }

  yourCallback(searchResults) {
    console.log("searchResults", searchResults);
    // set the state with the result
    this.setState({searchResults});
  }

  render() {
  // console.log ('this.props', this.props)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Searching
           callback={this.yourCallback}
        />
      <br/>
      // Show that state
      {
       this.state.searchResults 
          ? this.state.searchResults.map((r) => 
             <h1>{r.id.videoId}</h1>) : null;
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. I get "TypeError: this.setState is not a function" I was wondering why .

Comment: @brohymn You need to bind `yourCallback` function in constructor. Check updated code of constructor.

Comment: I get 
proxyConsole.js:56 Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {kind, etag, id, snippet}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `App

However, if I add       <h1>{this.state.searchResults.id}</h1> the error goes away, but still nothing shows inside the h1 tag

Comment: @brohymn Your `searchResults` is an array. So you need to iterate that array. Check update.

Comment: got it , thank you sir. I was suspecting the array map thing had something to do with it I just didnt want to believe it.

Answer (score 0):

"TypeError: this.setState is not a function" signifies that your app is unable to find reference of "this".

You are supposed to bind the callback function with the context.

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
   // Maintain a state
   this.state = {
     searchResults: ""
   }
   this. yourCallback = this. yourCallback.bind(this);
 }
 //rest of your code here...
}
```